# Spring Data Multiple Transaction Control

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

The question is about using multiple transaction in crudrepository, jparepository ext.
In my project, there are two entities. `RequestEntity` and `SendingMailEntity`.
WorkFlow in my method:

1) save `RequestEntity` ,

2) send `informationService`(it is an rest service that purchased by us. we can't control its any exception.)

3) save `SendingMailEntity`.

When there is an exception on number 2 or 3, we lost `requestEntity` because of rollback that is controlled by spring jpa.

The records of `requestEntity` are never to be lost.

How can I control this issue ? How can I have two independent transaction in spring data ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you please post a minimum code example of your method? Is it annotated @Transactional? The question itself doesn't say much right now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a method in your service specifically for managing / saving the `requestEntity` and annotate it appropriately so that the current transaction is paused, and this code run in a new transaction and commited upon exit from the method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void processRequestEntity(...){
    // jpa repo actions
}
```